# Gradle version stuck at v4.4

Tags: android-studio, gradle

I am trying to build a project that has built successfully only days before and over years past (not a new project).  Now, I am running into build exception.

Gradle is using a different version (4.4) than that specified in Android Studio Project Structure (4.10.1), or the Gradle files.

Project Structure:

[image]

`gradle-wrapper-properties` file:

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.10.1-all.zip
```

The build error is:

```
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> Failed to apply plugin [id 'com.android.application']
   > Minimum supported Gradle version is 4.6. Current version is 4.4. If using the gradle wrapper, try editing the distributionUrl in /Users/jeffrey/AndroidStudioProjects/vmem/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties to gradle-4.6-all.zip
```

I have **invalidated caches and restarted A Studio**

What is going on - where is it getting the 4.4 from?  Is there a cache somewhere that needs to get cleared separately?  Where else should I look?

Answer (score 0):

A few options:

1. Goto File->Settings and look for offline under Gradle. Make sure offline is unchecked.
2. You'll see a file path there for the Gradle cache. Open it and delete the problematic versions. 4.10 and 4.6 if you have them.
3. Goto the project folder and delete the .gradle and cache.
4. Reopen AS and the project. Do Build->Clean and Build->Rebuild project
5. Make sure you see that As download gradle again at the beginning of the build.

Also are there any other errors or warnings?

Did you upgrade gradle for some reason?

Comment: I just upgraded gradle:  `brew upgrade gradle` and problem is solved.